# Strange Behaviour on MSSQL Stored Procedure using Conditional WHERE with CONTAINS (Full Text Index)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures, where-clause

I need some help from a MS SQL Master...

**Short version:**
When I execute a Conditional Where followed by a Contains, my query delays 1 minute (In its normal execution, it takes 200 milliseconds).

With this query, everything works fine:

```
Where
   Contains(table.product_name, @search_word)
```

But with a Conditional Where, it takes 1 minute to execute:

```
Where
   (@ExecuteWhereStatement = 0 Or (Contains(table.product_name, @search_word))
```

**Long Version:**
I'm using a stored procedure that receives some parameters. This Stored Procedure query a really large table, but everything is indexed properly and the query goes very well so far.
The main query is a little big, so I want to make the WHERE clause more smart possible, to avoid repeat multiple times the same statement.

The whole idea of the DataBase, is a history of purchases made by the State. So this query involves 3 tables:

Table 1 (table_purchase) - The purchase itself

```
id_purchase        int (PK)
date_purchase      datetime
buyer_code         int (Nullable)
```

Table 2 (table_purchase_product) - The Items of a Purchase

```
id_product              int (PK)
id_purchase             int (FK of table_purchase)
product_quantity        int (Nullable)
product_name            varchar(255) (Nullable) (Full-Text-Indexed)
product_description     varchar(2000) (Nullable) (Full-Text-Indexed)
id_product_bid_winner   int (FK of table_product_bid)
```

Table 3 (table_product_bids) - The Bids for Each product of a Purchase

```
id_product_bid  int (PK)
id_product      int (FK of table_purchase_product)
product_brand   varchar(255) (Nullable) (Full-Text-Indexed)
bid_value       decimal (20,6)
```

So basicly, We have a "Purchase", that has several "Products (or Items)", and each "Product" has some "Bids (or Prices)"

And there is the Bad Girl (The SQL Stored Procedure):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[procPesquisaFullText]

@search_date        datetime,
@search_word        varchar(8000),
@search_brand       varchar(255),
@only_one_bid       bit = 0,
@search_buyer_code  int = 0,
@quantityFrom       decimal(20,6) = 0,
@quantityTo         decimal(20,6) = 0

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;


Declare @ExecuteWordSearch AS bit;
if (@uasg != 0 And @search_word = '')
    begin
        Set @ExecuteWordSearch = 0;
        Set @search_word = 'nothing';
    end

else
    begin 
        Set @ExecuteWordSearch = 1;
    end

Declare @ExecuteBrandSearch AS bit;
if (@search_brand = '')
    begin
        Set @ExecuteBrandSearch = 0;
        Set @search_brand = 'nothing';
    end

else
    begin 
        Set @ExecuteMarcaSearch = 1;
    end


    begin
        SELECT
                pp.id_product,
                pp.id_purchase,
                pp.description

        FROM            
                table_purchase_product pp
                inner join table_purchase p on p.id_purchase = pp.id_purchase

        WHERE
                (p.date_purchase >= @search_date)
                and (@search_buyer_code = 0 or (l.buyer_code = @search_buyer_code))

                and (@quantityFrom = 0 or (li.product_quantity >= @QuantityFrom))
                and (@quantityTo = 0 or (li.product_quantity <= @QuantityTo))

                and (contains(pp.product_description, @search_word) or contains(pp.product_name, @search_word))

                and (@only_one_bid = 0
                or ((Select COUNT(*) From table_product_bid Where table_product_bid.id_product = pp.id_product) = 1))

                and (@ExecuteBrandSearch = 0 Or (exists(
                        select  1
                        from    table_product_bid ppb
                        where   ppb.id_product_bid = pp.id_product_bid_winner
                                and contains(ppb.product_brand, @search_brand)
                        )
                    ))

        ORDER BY p.date_purchase DESC
    end
END
```

So far, so good...

In the beginning I set two variables, used inside the query.

The first, verify if the user specified a "Buyer Code" AND didn't specify a "Search Word" (So, not the Product's description nor the Product's name is verified)

The second, verify if the user specified a "Specific Brand". If so, then the Winning Bid's BRAND is verified to match the users one.

Observation: You'll notice that when the "Search Words" is empty, I set them to "nothing". I do it because if the search term in the Contains is empty, it throws me a exception, even when it's not executed (I tested it in another query, absolutely isolated too)

As You can see, my user is able to search for:
 - "Products" of Some Distinct Buyer "Purchase" (passing the @search_buyer_code parameter)
 - A "Product" that contains a distinct word in its name or description
 - A "Product" that has the Winner Bid of a specific Brand
 - A "Product" that has only 1 bid at all
 - A "Product" with a maximum and minimum quantity

And You'll notice that I used a lot of Conditions INSIDE the Where, producing a very dynamic Where, instead of using a "BIG If Else" statement, and repeating a lot of code. (I guess some "Googlers" will land here looking for Conditionally Wheres, and If so, I'm glad to help!)

Ok, so everything works veeery great at all. The query executes flawless. But here is the strange, damn, tricky issue:
If I want the user to be able to specify only a "Buyer Code" for Purchase, but No Word to Search of the Product using the code above (which is the first piece of code in the stored procedure does):

Changing from:

```
and (contains(pp.product_description, @search_word) or contains(pp.product_name, @search_word))
```

To:

```
and (@ExecuteWordSearch = 0 Or (contains(pp.product_description, @search_word) or contains(pp.product_name, @search_word)))
```

The query delays near 1 minute! (the execution is about 200 milliseconds for the query above).

But WHY??? I Use the same Logic of in all "Conditionally Wheres". I also use the same logic of having a flag/variable to indicate when execute the Where clause in the Word Search and the Brand Search, but the Brand Search works PERFECTLY! So Why, WHY only when I use the condition followed by a Contains my query delays 1 minute????

And this issue is not related with the amount of data, because I tried removing the entire Contains condition, allowing a lot of data to return, and it takes 1 second maximum...

Ow, It's a Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2.

Thanks already for You read so far!

Comment: Sql server does not short circuit the conditions in where clause, even if `@ExecuteWordSearch = 0` evaluates to true, it might go ahead and check the other condition anyway. Try using Dynamic Sql.

Comment: Are you sure? Because the other conditions, I can notice undoubtedly the difference when the where is executed and not.  
Mostly when the "Brand Where" is executed, it takes the double of time to execution).
And Even if it really happens, the query don't may take more time to execution (considering it will verify anyway)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot find the documentation I had around a very similar issue, but it sounded so familiar, I at least wanted to share what I remembered. Part of the issue is that for Sql Server, the full-text search engine is separate from the regular query execution engine, and so when you mix the two, in some cases, performance can tank. This is particularly true when the condition is an 'OR' rather than and 'AND'. (I remember hitting this exact situation). Conditional `AND`s worked fine. But for `OR`, it's *as if* each condition gets evaluated repeatedly row by row.

Among the workarounds, one is, as already suggested, create your sql dynamically before execution.
Another would be to break the full-text and non-full text conditions into two search functions (literally UDF's) and then do whatever is needed (`INTERSECT`, `EXCEPT`, etc) with the two resultsets.

Comment: Thanks, that explain a lot, because in just few records (limited by other filters before the contains) the query was executed fast. And as much rows I was increasing in result, more (a lot more actually, not the normal more like milliseconds) slow was the query.
And testing with the AND operator does exactly how You described (worked fine).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your WHERE clause to use a CASE statement, e.g.:

```
WHERE
    CASE 
        WHEN @ExecuteWhereStatement = 0 THEN 1 
        WHEN @ExecuteWhereStatement = 1 THEN
            CASE 
                WHEN CONTAINS([table].product_name, @search_word) THEN 1 
                ELSE 0 
            END 
    END = 1;
```

Comment: Still same problem. In fact, I think this is just another way to write same thing. Can't see how the engine would compile/execute this in different way...